# How to find method which call threadPool

Tags: java, stack-trace

I have some bug in production's application, but I can't find the cause of it. I try to get some log to find a method, which calls my `method()`. But because I use threadPool I can't just get `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and iterate through StackTraceElements, it shows only some lines before ThreadPool.
If I use the next code, I'll get every method which I need, but it so expansive. Only 1 call of method cost 400+ Kb in a text file in my test environment. In production it would be about 1 Mb in a second, I think.

```
private final ExecutorService completableFutureExecutor =
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 2000, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<>());

public void firstMethod(){

    secondMethod();    
}

private CompletableFuture<Void> secondMethod(){

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->method(),threadPool);

}

void method(){
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> map = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
        for (Thread thread : map.keySet()) {
            printLog(thread);
        }
}
private void printLog(Thread thread) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (StackTraceElement s : thread.getStackTrace()) {
            builder.append("\n getClass = " + s.getClass());
            builder.append("\n getClassName = " + s.getClassName());
            builder.append("\n getFileName = " + s.getFileName());
            builder.append("\n getLineNumber = " + s.getLineNumber());
            builder.append("\n getMethodName = " + s.getMethodName());
            builder.append("\n  ---------------------------- \n ");
        }
        ownLogger.info("SomeThread = {} ", builder);
    }
```

How to find that `firstMethod()` who calls `secondMethod()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I haven't found any good solution my own is to put logger before and after CompletableFuture call

It looks like

```
Logger beforeAsync= LoggerFactory.getLogger("beforeAsync");
Logger afterAsync= LoggerFactory.getLogger("afterAsync");

private CompletableFuture<Void> secondMethod(){
    printLongerTrace(Thread.currentThread(),beforeAsync);
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->method(),threadPool);
}

private void methodWithException(){
    try{
    //do something
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 
      printLongerTrace(e,"methodWithException", afterAsync);
    }
}

public void printLongerTrace(Throwable t, String methodName, Logger ownlogger) {

    if (t.getCause() != null) {
        printLongerTrace(t.getCause(), methodName, fields, ownlogger);
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("\n Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    builder.append("ERROR CAUSE = " + t.getCause() + "\n");
    builder.append("ERROR MESSAGE = " + t.getMessage() + "\n");

    printLog(t.getStackTrace(), builder);
    ownlogger.info(methodName + "Trace ----- {}", builder);
}

public void printLongerTrace(Thread t, Logger ownlogger) {

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("\n Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    printLog(t.getStackTrace(), builder);
    ownlogger.info("Trace ----- {}", builder);
}

private StringBuilder printLog(StackTraceElement[] elements, StringBuilder builder) {

    int size = elements.length > 15 ? 15 : elements.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        builder.append("Line " + i + " = " + elements[i] + "   with method = " + elements[i].getMethodName() + "\n");
    }
    return builder;
}
```

`printLongerTrace(Throwable t, String methodName, Logger ownlogger)` needs to print exception with every cause in recursion.

`printLongerTrace(Thread t, Logger ownlogger)` needs to print which method call before CompletableFuture

Answer (score -1):

Just dump the Stack by calling `Thread.dumpStack()` but this is only for debugin and has a big overhead, since dumping the stack is cpu intensive

Comment: because of that, I ask, how to avoid overloading production's server. Also   `public static void dumpStack() {
        new Exception("Stack trace").printStackTrace();
    }` doesn't show what I am looking for. It is similar Thread.currentThread.getStackTrace();

Comment: Since getting the stacktrace is allways cpu intensive, you cant avoid that, the least cpu intensive method is `new Exception().printStackTrace()`

Comment: Try getting the currentThread by `Thread.currentThread()` and only print the stacktrace of that thread

Comment: It shows also some methods till pool like `com.service.impl.secondMethod.lambda$method$35(MainClass.java:1292)   with method = lambda$completableFeeds$35
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)   with method = run
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)   with method = runWorker
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)   with method = run
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)   with method = run`

Comment: The problem is the lambda you used, java has problems showing errors correctly in lambdas

Comment: It wouldn't be any problem with Anonymous class? I thought that problem in CompletableFuture

Comment: The CompletableFuture only submits the task to the threadpool, and allows you to wait for a result, it just calls run on youre interface, in this case the lambda

Comment: log changed only to `com.service.impl.secondMethod.get$1(MainClass.java:1292)` when I used
`CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void get() {
                return collectorService.method();
            }
        }, completableFutureExecutor);`
Other lines without changing (

Comment: voted down because of Dred's explanations here, will still only show the stack for the thread